# Issue in adding dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 datepickers binded to 2 text boxes(`Chkin` and `Chkout`). When I select a date in `Chkin` Im supposed to show `Chkin`+1 date in `Chkout`. But `Chkout` date are not properly filled in some cases. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?
My code is-

```
$("#Chkin").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat:  $("#Dateformat").val(),
            minDate: '+0',               
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                if ($("#Dateformat").val() == "dd/mm/yy") {
                    var parts = dateText.split("/");
                    var cin = new Date(Number(parts[2]), Number(parts[1]) - 1, Number(parts[0]));
                }
                else {
                    var cin = new Date(dateText);
                }
                var cout = new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate()+1); 
                var maxOut= new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate()+7);
                $("#Chkout").datepicker('option', 'minDate', cout); 
                $("#Chkout").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxOut);
                showDays();
            } 
        });
        var cin = new Date($("#Chkin").val());
        var cout = new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate()+1);   
        var maxOut= new Date(cin.getFullYear(), cin.getMonth(), cin.getDate()+7);
        $("#Chkout").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat:  $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnDateformat").val(), 
            minDate: cout, 
            maxDate: maxOut,
            onSelect: showDays });
```

**PS:`Chkin` and `Chkout` values are initially binded with some dates.**

Comment: In what way is the ckout date not calculated properly? Have you verified that the bug is in your code, versus the 3rd party datepicker? Some quick thoughts-- always initialize new dates to midnight (e.g. new Date(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0, 0)), to avoid daylight savings weirdnesses. Also, is the year really 2-digit? If you only pass a 1- or 2-digit year to the Date constructor, it assumes the century is 19 (e.g. new Date(7, ...) == 1907).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when `Chkin` is closed, you don't set `Chkout` with `Chkin` + 1.

In your `$("#Chkin").datepicker({})`, add `$("#Chkout").datepicker( "setDate", cout );` before call function `showDays()`.

Explanation :

With your current code, if selected value in `Chkin` is less than 7 days OR equal to `Chkout`, `Chkout` will automatically set to `Chkin` + 1. But otherwise, `Chkout` will not be changed.

Example :

Before `Chkin` is changed :

```
Chkin = 1 August 2013
Chkout = 5 August 2013
Chkout's minDate and maxDate = 2 August 2013 and 8 August 2013
```

Case 1 - `Chkin` is changed to 22 July 2013 :

```
Chkout = 23 July 2013
Chkout's minDate and maxDate = 23 July 2013 and 29 July 2013
```

Case 1 explanation : *`Chkout` is changed because old Chkout's value is not in range of new Chkout's minDate and maxDate*.

Case 2 - `Chkin` is changed to 3 August 2013 :

```
Chkout = 5 August 2013
Chkout's minDate and maxDate = 4 August 2013 and 10 August 2013
```

Case 2 explanation : *`Chkout` is still same because old Chkout's value is in range of new Chkout's minDate and maxDate*.

Hopefully this help.